# AWS EKS Node Group nodes fail to join the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am trying to add a Node Group to an EKS Cluster, but no matter what I try, creation of the Node Group fails.

> NodeCreationFailure:  Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

In CloudTrail there are no errors for the `AWS::EKS::Cluster`, `AWS::EKS::Nodegroup` and `AWS::EC2::Instance` resources created by the CloudFormation template.

And in CloudWatch, there there are no errors in any of the EKS logs. All logs (`api`, `audit`, `authenticator`, `controllerManager` and `scheduler`) are on.

I've followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#worker-node-fail), but I don't believe that my issue lies with any of the topics covered there.

I've also attempted to run the [AWSSupport-TroubleshootEKSWorkerNode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-troubleshooteksworkernode.html) runbook, but that fails, saying that my cluster doesn't exists, although it does and is healthy.

Is anyone able to suggest a resolution?

---

## Troubleshooting

### Nodes fail to join cluster

##### The [aws-auth-cm.yaml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) file doesn't have the correct IAM role ARN for your nodes.

The Node IAM role contains the permissions as [described in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-node-role.html), and I have confirmed that the role has been added to the `aws-auth` config map.

##### The ClusterName in your node AWS CloudFormation template doesn't exactly match the name of the cluster you want your nodes to join.

I'm using `ClusterName: !Ref EksCluster` to set the name of the cluster. It exactly matches.

##### The node is not tagged as being owned by the cluster.

The node group successfully creates and Auto Scaling Group, which successfully starts an EC2 instance (all status checks pass). The instance has the tag `kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster = owned` applied to it.

##### The nodes may not be able to access the cluster using a public IP address.

- The EKS cluster has `EndpointPrivateAccess = true` and `EndpointPublicAccess = false`.
- The EC2 instance is associated with an Elastic Network Interface in a private subnet that is in the same Availability Zone.
- There is a NAT Gateway in the same AZ as the private subnet.
- A route from the private subnet to the NAT Gateway exists.

##### The STS endpoint for the AWS Region that you're deploying the nodes to is not enabled for your account.

- The STS endpoint for the region is enabled.

##### The worker node doesn't have a private DNS entry

The DHCP Options Set used by the VPC has values `domain-name:<region>.compute.internal` and `domain-name-servers:AmazonProvidedDNS`.

### Managed node group errors

##### NodeCreationFailure

As mentioned above, the Node IAM role contains the permissions as [described in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-node-role.html).

Additionally, the private subnet that the node resides in has outbound access to the internet.

Comment: Were you able to resolve? I m facing the same for al2023 custom ami.